# EF Designer from database - can't select tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Trying to create EF Designer from database. Becouse of unknown reason I can't select Tables. My clicking on box doesn't gives any influence on it:

[image]

Why? How to fix that?

Comment: You either don't have any tables or the credentials used don't have access to any tables. Have you verified this outside of EF?

Comment: This depends on credential permissions or table existence, is that the DB has predefined tables & using privileged user which able to access tables?

Comment: Ok, this was the problem. Fixed. I can accept answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Entity Framework does not list any tables it's because this database does not have any tables defined or the credentials used to connect do not have access to any tables.

You must verify this outside of EF and grant access to the appropriate tables, when you run this wizard again the tables will be listed.